# Zero not added list

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" valueType="int" columnDef="2" itemIndex="9.1" placeHolder="the number of children under 15 years of age" operation="compare(s9i1,lt)">0</input>
```

A zero must appear here

IT SHOULD BE ZERO ON THE LIST BUT IT DOES NOT COME ZERO

Comment: Input element is not supposed to have children. You should use the "0" as value or placeholder.

Comment: `input` is a replaced element. This means it has no closing tag and no text or child nodes. To show 0 in the input use the value attribute: `<input type="number" value="0">`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `value` attribute. An input can not have a child element:

```html
<input type="text" value="0" valueType="int" columnDef="2" itemIndex="9.1" placeHolder="the number of children under 15 years of age" operation="compare(s9i1,lt)"></input>
```